# Spacemacs disable :q

Tags: spacemacs

I'm moving from vim to spacemacs, and the only little frustration I have at the moment is that in vim my workflow tends to involve quitting vim a lot (with :q). I find myself continually exiting spacemacs by mistake - and having to wait for it to restart. Habits die hard. How can I either remap ':q' to quit the buffer (and not spacemacs) or disable ':q' completely to force myself to learn to kill buffers the spacemacs way?

Comment: I think you can continue your workflow if you start emacs as a daemon and run emacsclient to actually edit files. Emacsclient will then start as fast as vim does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding the following to my config file (~/.spacemacs) resolved the problem:

```
(evil-ex-define-cmd "q[uit]" nil)
```

This can also be used to modify the behaviour of the ex command line by replacing nil with a function name, e.g.

```
(evil-ex-define-cmd "q[uit]" 'evil-window-delete )
```

Answer (score 3):

I've never used spacemacs before or evil mode but it would make sense to rebind the key to not do anything like this:

```
(define-key evil-ex-map "q" nil)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't quite get there, but after some searching I found the following solution work   (evil-ex-define-cmd "q[uit]" nil)

Comment: @Mark Why not add that as an answer to your question and accept it?